# how get inspect element of the page web

Tags: html, element, inspect

I want to get **inspect element of the page web** . I've tried Jsoup to get html but it only returns the source code. So is there a way to get the code fully like the one in the **Inspect elements**? or is there a way to get code from Inspect Elements? Thanks !

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this element that you want to inspect?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend using Chrome.  Then use **Inspect Element** to get the code.  If you want to actually download all of the source code, you should just go to **File -> Save Page As...** to get all the code.

Save the code to your desktop and you'll have everything you need to open the site locally in your browser.

Comment: I want to be a operation automatic by Java i have try using jsoup and stream but there is no effect